# rails partial's layouts with named yield - why is yield block never used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, partials, content-for

I have a partial, with a layout:

```
<%= render :partial => 'home/mobile/home', :layout => 'home/mobile/page', :locals => {:page => 'abc2'}%>
```

The layout (page.html.erb) has yields for different blocks, such as:

```
<div data-role="header">
  <%= yield :header %>
</div>
```

However, this yield block is never used, while the main-level layout file does yield as one would expect.

Is it impossible to use named content_for/yield blocks with the layouts of partials? Are there workarounds?

I would expect inheritance-- content_for :header should first look for a yield :header in the partial's layout, and failing that, the main layout file.  But this is not the case.  The partial layout's yield :header is simply ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround would be to wrap your layout into an helper method using [blocks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/40-blocks-in-view) (which should be able to yield correctly).

You may want to fil a bug about the original problem.

Comment: think you'd have to hack this a bit to get it working with rails 3

Answer (score 7):

In a situation similar to yours, I replaced the `yield` with a call to `content_for` without a block. So in your example it would be simply:

```
<div data-role="header">
  <%= content_for :header %>
</div>
```

That worked for me. That `yield`s in partials don't trickle up as you suggest may be a feature or a bug - but that's still appear to be how it works in Rails 4.1.8, 3 years down the line :)

Comment: still the case with Rails 6!